# Terminal stuck at empty screen

Tags: macos, terminal, performance

The terminal app is stuck on a window like the following and doesn't respond to

- Reopen,
- File > Reset, hard reset.
- Renaming .bash_profile and reopen.
- Opening other profiles.

Last time I used it, it was for a nodejs server. After I was done using the server, I closed the Terminal window and hit Terminate when it asked if it should kill running processes.

[image]

Comment: I noticed your terminal window has the word 'login' in the title bar.  Normally it would have the name of the shell (e.g. bash, zsh, etc.)  Open 'System Preferences' -> 'User & Groups', right-click the user (unlock the padlock in lower-left corner if necessary) and select 'Advanced Options...'  What "Login shell" is specified?

Comment: @TimCampbell `/bin/bash`

Comment: ~/.bash_profile is only processed if a shell is a "login" shell (when you log into the machine).  Opening a Terminal window isn't a login shell -- so ~/.bash_profile is ignored.  But ~/.bashrc *is* processed.  Check your ~/.bashrc  I also sometimes suggest creating a new temporary user account and testing with that.  If that works, it means something in your (real user's) settings is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I had this issue resolved by doing what I wrote in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire up Activity Monitor and kill the process(es) named "node".